# EditText get hide when keyboard open

Tags: android

```
/*This is my  mainActivity.class*/

     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{       

        attachFragments();

      }

private void attachFragments() {

        CustomFragment chatFragment=new CustomFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.first, chatFragment);
        transaction.commit();

    }

}



/*mainActivity.xml*/



  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       < com.prospus.poms.layout.CustomSlidingLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    </com.prospus.poms.layout.CustomSlidingLayout>


CustomSlidingLayout.java


public class CustomSlidingLayout extends LinearLayout {

private static final int SLIDING_DURATION = 500;

private static final int QUERY_INTERVAL = 16;

int mainLayoutWidth;

private View menuRight;
private View content;

private enum MenuState {
    HIDING, HIDDEN, SHOWING, SHOWN,
};

private int contentXOffset;
private int menuWidth;
private int rightMenuOffset;

private MenuState currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;

private Scroller menuScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
        new EaseInInterpolator());

private Runnable rightMenuRunnable = new MenuRightRunnable();
private Handler menuHandler = new Handler();

public CustomSlidingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomSlidingLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    menuWidth=mainLayoutWidth;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    content = this.getChildAt(0);
    menuRight = getChildAt(1);
    menuRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    if (changed) {
        LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) content
                .getLayoutParams();
        contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
        contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();
        LayoutParams    menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) menuRight.getLayoutParams();
        menuLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
        menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();

    }

    menuRight.layout(right - rightMenuOffset, top, right - rightMenuOffset
            + menuWidth, bottom);
    content.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

public void toggleRightMenu() {
    if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
            || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
        return;

    switch (currentMenuState) {
    case HIDDEN:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
        menuRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0,
                -menuRight.getLayoutParams().width, 0, SLIDING_DURATION);

        contentXOffset = 0;
        rightMenuOffset = 0;
        invalidate();
        break;
    case SHOWN:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
        menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                SLIDING_DURATION);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }


    menuHandler.postDelayed(rightMenuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);

    this.invalidate();
}

protected class MenuRightRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isScrolling = menuScroller.computeScrollOffset();
        adjustRightContentPosition(isScrolling);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

private void adjustRightContentPosition(boolean isScrolling) {
    int scrollerXOffset = menuScroller.getCurrX();

    menuRight.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerXOffset - contentXOffset);
    rightMenuOffset += (contentXOffset-scrollerXOffset );
    contentXOffset = scrollerXOffset;
    this.invalidate();

    if (isScrolling)
        menuHandler.postDelayed(rightMenuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
    else
        this.onMenuSlidingComplete();
}

private void onMenuSlidingComplete() {
    switch (currentMenuState) {
    case SHOWING:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWN;
        break;
    case HIDING:
        currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
}
protected class EaseInInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float t) {
        return (float) Math.pow(t - 1, 5) + 1;
    }

}

public boolean isMenuShown() {
    return currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWN;
}
```

}

```
/*I am using this customlayout in main activity and in each sub layout attching a fragment. */




 /* Layout file of fragment:  */

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <include layout="@layout/header_layout" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/chatList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:divider="@android:color/black"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/title_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/upload"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/BASE_50_DP"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upload_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/chattext"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/BASE_5_DP"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/BASE_5_DP"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:maxHeight="@dimen/EditTextHeight"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/BASE_45_DP"
                android:padding="@dimen/BASE_5_DP"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="false" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/BASE_50_DP"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/done"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

kayboard hide the editText but when keyboard hides, editText comes in middle of screen. Exactly opposite the requirement. I know main problem is my custom layout. Please tell me what is wrong in this customlayout. Everything works fine if i replace the customLayout with relativeLayoot. but i have to use this layout. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <include layout="@layout/header_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/chatList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/black"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_thumb"
            android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_track"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/title_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/upload"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/BASE_50_DP"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/upload_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/upload_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chattext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/BASE_5_DP"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/BASE_5_DP"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:maxHeight="@dimen/EditTextHeight"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/BASE_45_DP"
            android:padding="@dimen/BASE_5_DP"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/BASE_50_DP"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/done"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/input_done_icon" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Used scroll view with windowSoftInputMethod="AdjustResize" 1. When first click on the keyboard  hides the editText. 2. when  press back btn keyboad disappear and scroll view takes only half screen height(left the height used for keyboard)this area show blank in this situation. 3. when i click on editText again then it comes in desired situation. Can you please give me solution of this problem

Comment: dont use any  windowSoftInputMethod for the particular activity

Answer (score 0):

put all view is scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
         <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include layout="@layout/header_layout" />
    </LinearLayout>       
     ..... 
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: When the keyboard disappear scrollView doesnot fill whole screen. area where the keyboard was appear shows blank after the keyboard disappear. please help

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole Relative layout inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

also

> NOTE that scrollview can only have 1 child view

and that will be your outermost reletive layout.

ans the above link to documentation for scrollview methods that can be used to set different properties in java file.